# When remote debugging, how to access source file on target

Tags: eclipse-cdt, jit, gdbserver

I'm using CDT to remotely debug an application.  The application constructs a 
source fragment and JITs it into memory.  For debugging, it creates an in-memory
ELF/DWARF image and registers it with the GDB JIT interface, and writes a source
file corresponding to the DWARF, to the local (target) filesystem.

The problem is that the debugger front-end then expects to find the source file on
the host filing system.  If I manually copy the source file from the target to the
host after every JIT event then the debugger can step through the source, but this
is impractical.  Having the JIT upload the file to the host would need the JIT to
be aware it was being debugged (and from where).  Is there a way to get gdbserver,
or CDT, to retrieve the source file, when needed, from the target filesystem?

I create the ELF/DWARF image that is passed to the GDB JIT interface, so I could
describe the source file location using an alternative path if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

The gdbserver protocol already supports [fetching remote files](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/File-Transfer.html#File-Transfer).

The trick then is to have GDB issue fetch command automatically in response to JIT events. This would be quite easy to do using Python scripting. Unfortunately, it looks like [JIT events are not exposed to Python](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Events-In-Python.html#Events-In-Python).

I suggest filing a feature request in [GDB bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb).